# El contenido se sale del bloque

Tags: html, css

tengo un pequeño inconveniente. Cabe destacar que tengo las librerías de js, jquery, bootstrap y todas las necesarias, en mi html.

Al intentar escribir dentro de un `alert` se sale el contenido, y no es lo que quiero, quiero que se vaya llenando y que el espacio del `alert`, ocupe la cantidad de letras o palabras que tenga, y no logro hacer que sea posible. 
¿Alguna ayuda?

Bueno, tengo el siguiente código a continuación:

```
<body> 
        <nav class="col-sm-12 navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username...">
                    </div>
                </form>
        </nav>
        <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">

            <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                <div class="alert alert-primary">
                    <strong>
                        alert-primarysadasdasdasdasdasd
                    </strong>
                    <span>
                        Prueba de componente
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                <div class="alert alert-secondary">
                    <strong>
                        alert-secondary
                    </strong>
                    <span>
                        Prueba de componente
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <strong>
                        alert-success
                    </strong>
                    <span>
                        Prueba de componente
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>
                        alert-danger
                    </strong>
                    <span>
                        Prueba de componente
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="col alert alert-warning">
                    <strong>
                        alert-warning
                    </strong>
                    <span>
                        Prueba de componente
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <strong>
                        alert-info
                    </strong>
                    <span>
                        Prueba de componente
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="alert alert-light">
                    <strong>
                        alert-light
                    </strong>
                    <span>
                        Prueba de componente
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="alert alert-dark ">
                    <strong>
                        alert-dark
                    </strong>
                    <span>
                        Prueba de componente
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo cual me genera algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como se ve, el contenido fuera del alert:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Trata con esto en cada contenedor  `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Si funciona. @BetaM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para romper la continuidad del texto y evitar se salga de su contenedor
Aplica a dicha etiqueta está regla css

```
etiqueta{
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```